# How to write reliable unittest for mobile web app under different devices, network?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, cordova, jasmine

I'm developing web apps based on PhoneGap. Basically I used Jasmine as my testing framework. But it's a pain for me to write robust unittests. I ran into these problems,

1. network may get unstable sometimes
2. device difference, some get high cpu frequency and large ram, some get low
3. gps signal may get strong or weak under different circumstance

The result of unittest may vary to above uncertain conditions. How to eliminate these side effect and get result more robust, reliable?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I can answer your actual question on how to eliminate these side effects since I don't know much about your environment. However I do think you can think about your tests differently in a way that may help.

Your unit tests shouldn't have to account for situations like "what if when running the test the signal gets weak". Instead you should have a unit test that will simulate that condition and then test for an expected behavior for your application under those conditions. When you can replicate the what-if situations you can then effectively write unit tests for them.

The next obvious question then is how to replicate the what-if conditions, which is something I'm not sure PhoneGap or Jasmine can really address directly. Maybe there is something you can control in a simulator that will effectively reproduce a weak network/gps signal. Differences in CPU/RAM power is something you'll probably just need a lot of devices to test on.

Comment: you suggested that simulate everything (environment, data, etc) in testing. Actually I ran all these tests on real device and I do want to test under real environment. I don't know if I mixed things up.

Comment: Testing in a real environment isn't really unit testing any more. I would say it's more integration testing, which is something you can write scripts for in Jasmine. However integration testing isn't something where you get to control as many variables. Have a look at this link to further describe the differences. 

http://www.typemock.com/blog/2011/05/29/the-difference-between-unit-testing-and-integration-testing-2/

Which I guess still doesn't give a way to control this environment variables but I think it might too difficult to do so.